# Menu Control For Navigation

Tags: asp.net, menu, navigation, controls

When I use "Menu" control, it gets information about menu items from "sitemap" file and I think the server build automatically "javascript" for this "Menu" control. Can I change this automatically builded javascript for this control ? If I want to have more good looking navigation bar what what is the prefer way to do:

To build my own navigation menu with javascript and css ?

Or

To find a way to change the "javascript" in "Menu" control ?

When should I use this "Menu" control ? If I use it, how to customize with my own prefer style ?

Answer (score 2):

### Question 1 - Giving unique appearance to a ASP.NET Menu:

The ASP.NET menu control, when rendered in HTML, is nothing more than a `ul` (unordered list).Simply apply a few CSS style rules to give it a unique appearance:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="menu">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" NavigateUrl="Home.aspx" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact us" NavigateUrl="ContactUs.aspx" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="About us" NavigateUrl="AboutUs.aspx" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .menu ul
    {
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    }

    .menu ul li
    {
        border: 1px solid white;
        background-color: gray;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 3px;
    }

    .menu ul li a
    {
        color: White;
    }

    .menu ul li a:hover
    {
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
```

**Result:**

[image]

### Question 2: ASP.NET Menu or CSS+Javascript menu:

This all depends on your required functionality.

If you're using the menu simply for navigation purposes then sure a simple CSS and javascript menu will suffice but if you're planning to dynamically generate menu items from a database and/or show hide certain menu items based on user roles then you would need to use something more powerful like an ASP.NET Menu control.That being said as you can see from my answer to Question1 you can easily add CSS as well as javascript to the Menu control, so it's very flexible in that regard.

---